# wrap google doc content with divs and turn into html file

Tags: html, arrays, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to turn google docs file into html file. I gave html tags to the content via google docs (h1, h2, p, etc) and then I downloaded it as HTML file and it works great.

I have one problem - I want to wrap specific contents in my google doc file with divs, a div for each chapter for example. Right now the file is just a list of html tags (h1, p, h2 etc) and I need it to be more correct hierarchically.

Is there a way to do that? I tried to use page break and other similar options but it just adds another element to the list and not wrapping a specific content in a div as I wish.
A javascript solution will be good too.

Would appreciate any help, Thanks!
Nir

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach on Google Apps Script. This is in no way the only solution. This is only a simple code you can try from many possible solutions available. Feel free to modify if needed depending on your use case.

#### Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var content = doc.getBody();
  var numChildren = content.getNumChildren();
  var output = [];
  // Send email to this address
  var sendTo = "test@gmail.com"; 

  output.push("<html><body>");
  for(var i=0; i < numChildren; i++){
    var item = content.getChild(i).asText();
    var text = item.getText();

    // Assuming that a chapter always starts in bold headers, we start the div there
    if(item.isBold()) {
      // Add opening div tags on every start of header, see doc format below
      output.push('<div>');
      output.push('<h1>' + text + '</h1>');
    }
    // If not bold, then that element is assumed as the content of the chapter
    else if (text){
      output.push('<p>' + text + '</p>');
    }
  }
  output.push("</body></html>");

  // Get all indices where div is (except the first) and reverse
  var indexes = getAllIndexes(output, "<div>");
  // Per div found, insert closing div tag </div> before it
  indexes.forEach(function(index){
    output.splice(index, 0, "</div>");
  });

  // Join output array and treat it as html
  var html = Utilities.newBlob(output.join(""), 'text/html', 'doc_to_html.html');
  // Send to your email (modify email above if needed) the converted file with div tags
  MailApp.sendEmail(sendTo, "Attached html-converted document", "file is attached below", {name: 'doc-to-html', attachments: [html], noReply: true});
}

function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
    var indexes = [], i = -1;
    while ((i = arr.indexOf(val, i+1)) != -1){
        indexes.push(i);
    }
    // Remove the first index (we don't need to add closing divs before the first div)
    indexes.shift();
    // Return reversed indices since we will add from the end since we are inserting closing div tags (</div>)
    // Inserting from the start will change the indices of those succeeding opening div tags (<div>) we need to close
    return indexes.reverse();
}
```

#### Email:

[image: output1]

#### HTML Attachment:

[image: output2]

#### Note:

- This was assumed that per chapter, there is a single header at the start (we insert the `<div>` here), and paragraph/s below it. The closing div tags `</divs>` are inserted every before the next `<div>` tags found.